# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Прошло три года после того, как Майк на пике своей популярности закончил карьеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно. Можно ещё поставить запятую перед "после того как" и убрать эту.

Этот составной союз либо расчленяется, либо ставится запятая перед ним и в конце всего оборота. Поскольку у вас им заканчивается предложение, о закрывающей запятой говорить не приходится.